# Adding the Eigen linear algebra library for c++ to the compiler

Tags: c++, eigen

I will be honest; I have no idea what I am doing. So, I am sorry if the title and my post are a bit confusing.

I need to compile programs using the C++ Eigen library, but I can't figure out where to put the library.

I have seen several command line methods using "$ git clone" and g++, but those commands all are returned as unrecognized by command prompt. I installed Cygwin reading that it was supposed to add the g++ command, but it didn't. I am trying to do all my programing using notepad++; however, I also tried using a compiler called JGrasp which refused to recognize the library.

I have already spent the better part of 3 hours on this and am more confused and lost than when I started. If someone could help me learn what I am supposed to be doing, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Put your library wherever you want.  Use the `-L` (capital ell) and the `-I` (captial i) command line options to tell the compiler where to look for your Eigen library.

Comment: First of all, forget about eigen. You need to write a "hello world" program and get that to compile and run.  JGrasp has nothing to do with your problem, and neither does git. You want to be able to say `g++ myprog.cpp` and have it compile and link `myprog.cpp`.

Comment: Anyone know a good question and answer here about how to compile link and run a C++ program on windows using GCC? I couldn't seem to find one, and If not, I might write one.

Comment: g++ is not a recognizable command. I assume I need to add an Environment Variable, but where would I find g++ so I can add the path? Also, is there a difference between -L and -I?

Comment: It's very unusual to have someone apparently starting out on C++ needing to use Eigen. It's a great template based, header file only library. All you need is to copy their header files and provide a path with a compiler flag. Why are you starting out with Eigen? There are better options for getting up to speed with C++.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with C++. I am just accustom to using a program that handles the libraries and has a built in compiler. I recently joined a project where I am going to need to use notepad++ and compile through command line. I was also told that I needed to use eigen for matrix calculations.

Comment: you mentioned cygwin, so this is windows? do you know what compiler you're using on windows?

Comment: Eigen is a header only library, so once you got your `helloworld.cpp` compiles, all you need is to pass `-I path/to/eigen` to `g++`. Don't forget `-O3` for compiler optimizations, otherwise Eigen will be very slow.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Cygwin apparently wasn't installing the g++ package. I found a video that showed how to install that package and then added the cygwin bin path to my path environment variable. I wrote a test program using the Eigen library which successfully compiled and executed using `g++ -I path/to/eigen testfile.cpp -o testfile`. Where would the `-03` go in that command?